# Emulate a Bluetooth Keyboard with a Raspberry Pi 3

Tags: python, pi-3, bluetooth, keyboard

**Raspberry Pi 2 Model B** (Raspbian Wheezy and bluez 4.99)

Executes perfectly using a Bluetooth dongle.

**Raspberry Pi 3 Model B** (Raspbian Jessie and bluez 4.99)

Attempting to pair with Windows laptop will fail and continue displaying the following:

```
Service record added
Waiting for a connection
```

Attempting to pair with Android device shows above message but Android says `Connecting...` for as long as Bluetooth is on.

```
#!/usr/bin/python2.7
#
# PiTooth allows the Raspberry Pi to act as a Bluetooth keyboard, and relays
# keypresses from a USB keyboard to a Bluetooth client. Written by Liam Fraser
# for a Linux User & Developer tutorial.
#

import os # Used to call external commands
import sys # Used to exit the script
import bluetooth
from bluetooth import *
import dbus # Used to set up the SDP record
import time # Used for pausing the process
import evdev # Used to get input from the keyboard
from evdev import *
import keymap # Used to map evdev input to hid keycodes

class Bluetooth:
    HOST = 0 # BT Mac address
    PORT = 1 # Bluetooth Port Number

# Define the ports we'll use
P_CTRL = 17
P_INTR = 19

def __init__(self):
    # Set the device class to a keyboard and set the name
    os.system("hciconfig hci0 class 0x002540")
    os.system("hciconfig hci0 name Raspberry\ Pi")
    # Make device discoverable
    os.system("hciconfig hci0 piscan")

    # Define our two server sockets for communication
    self.scontrol = BluetoothSocket(L2CAP)
    self.sinterrupt = BluetoothSocket(L2CAP)

    # Bind these sockets to a port
    self.scontrol.bind(("", Bluetooth.P_CTRL))
    self.sinterrupt.bind(("", Bluetooth.P_INTR))

    # Set up dbus for advertising the service record
    self.bus = dbus.SystemBus()
    try:
        self.manager = dbus.Interface(self.bus.get_object("org.bluez", "/"),
                                                          "org.bluez.Manager")
        adapter_path = self.manager.DefaultAdapter()
        self.service = dbus.Interface(self.bus.get_object("org.bluez", adapter_path),
                                                          "org.bluez.Service")
    except:
        sys.exit("Could not configure bluetooth. Is bluetoothd started?")

    # Read the service record from file
    try:
        fh = open(sys.path[0] + "/sdp_record.xml", "r")
    except:
        sys.exit("Could not open the sdp record. Exiting...")            
    self.service_record = fh.read()
    fh.close()

def listen(self):
    # Advertise our service record
    self.service_handle = self.service.AddRecord(self.service_record)
    print "Service record added"

    # Start listening on the server sockets
    self.scontrol.listen(1) # Limit of 1 connection
    self.sinterrupt.listen(1)
    print "Waiting for a connection"
    self.ccontrol, self.cinfo = self.scontrol.accept()
    print "Got a connection on the control channel from " + self.cinfo[Bluetooth.HOST]
    self.cinterrupt, self.cinfo = self.sinterrupt.accept()
    print "Got a connection on the interrupt channel from " + self.cinfo[Bluetooth.HOST]

def send_input(self, ir):
    # Convert the hex array to a string
    hex_str = ""
    for element in ir:
        if type(element) is list:
            # This is our bit array - convert it to a single byte represented
            # as a char
            bin_str = ""
            for bit in element:
                bin_str += str(bit)
            hex_str += chr(int(bin_str, 2))
        else:
            # This is a hex value - we can convert it straight to a char
            hex_str += chr(element)
    # Send an input report
    self.cinterrupt.send(hex_str)


class Keyboard():
    def __init__(self):
        # The structure for an bt keyboard input report (size is 10 bytes)
        self.state = [ 
               0xA1, # This is an input report
               0x01, # Usage report = Keyboard
               # Bit array for Modifier keys (D7 being the first element, D0 being last)
               [0,   # Right GUI - (usually the Windows key) 
                0,   # Right ALT
                0,   # Right Shift
                0,   # Right Control
                0,   # Left GUI - (again, usually the Windows key)
                0,   # Left ALT
                0,   # Left Shift
                0],  # Left Control
               0x00, # Vendor reserved
               0x00, # Rest is space for 6 keys 
               0x00,
               0x00,
               0x00,
               0x00,
               0x00 ]

        # Keep trying to get a keyboard
        have_dev = False
        while have_dev == False:
            try:
                # Try and get a keyboard - should always be event0 as we're only
                # plugging one thing in
                self.dev = InputDevice("/dev/input/event0")
                have_dev = True
            except OSError:
                print "Keyboard not found, waiting 3 seconds and retrying"
                time.sleep(3)

        print "Found a keyboard"

    def change_state(self, event):
        evdev_code = ecodes.KEY[event.code]
        modkey_element = keymap.modkey(evdev_code)
        if modkey_element > 0:
            # Need to set one of the modifier bits
            if self.state[2][modkey_element] == 0:
                self.state[2][modkey_element] = 1
            else:
                self.state[2][modkey_element] = 0
        else:
            # Get the hex keycode of the key
            hex_key = keymap.convert(ecodes.KEY[event.code])
            # Loop through elements 4 to 9 of the input report structure
            for i in range (4, 10):
                if self.state[i] == hex_key and event.value == 0:
                    # Code is 0 so we need to depress it
                    self.state[i] = 0x00
                elif self.state[i] == 0x00 and event.value == 1:
                    # If the current space is empty and the key is being pressed
                    self.state[i] = hex_key
                    break

    def event_loop(self, bt):
        for event in self.dev.read_loop():
            # Only bother if we a key and it's an up or down event
            if event.type == ecodes.EV_KEY and event.value < 2:
                    self.change_state(event)
                    bt.send_input(self.state)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # We can only run as root
    if not os.geteuid() == 0:
        sys.exit("Only root can run this script")

    bt = Bluetooth()
    bt.listen()
    kb = Keyboard()
    kb.event_loop(bt)
```

Comment: Yousef Abdelsalam Have you resolved the issue ? I was also trying to achieve something similar. Your response will be vary valuable for me .

Comment: @swathykrishnan Yes, I just wrote the exact same img from RPi 2 to the RPi 3 w/o updating anything and it works!